# Finding a constant to make a valid pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $f(x) = c\cdot 2^{-x^2}$. How do I find a constant $c$ such that the integral evaluates to $1$?

Comment: Since you already have two answers showing that $f(x) = c\, e^{-x^2\ln(2)}$, I will suggest that rather than the error function, you simply use what I hope you already know: $$\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)}~~\text{is the density function of a}~N(0,\sigma^2)~ \text{random variable}.$$ Now compare constants and deduce the value of $c$.  As a side benefit, you also get the mean and variance of the random variable for free.

Answer (score 4):

You can write $2^{-x^2}$ as $$2^{-x^2}=e^{(\ln 2)({-x^2})}=e^{-x^2\ln 2}$$Using the error function you can calculate the integral 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2\ln 2}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\ln 2}}$$ The rest is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Rewrite
$$f(x) = c \,[e^{\ln(2)}]^{-x^2} = c\, e^{-x^2\ln(2)}$$
and try to exploit the following integral together with some change of variable:
$$
\int^{\infty}_0 e^{-x^2} \,dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
$$